# How do I get Retrospective feedback for an event using a Webform (participant Custom Data)?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, participants

Is there a way to get 'retrospective' feedback from participants for an event?

I'm struggling to find any way to access Custom (or any) participant fields without the form becoming one for Registration of an event - at which time they are not going to be avle to give feedback.

Does anyone have any knowledge of how to get Custom Participant fields into webforms when not registering the users?

Any light shed would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OK - I have it,
for this I've set up a Scheduled Job that fires off to "attended" participants a few days after the event. I set up a smart group of "participants whos participatory date was after [a month ago]" so i didn't spam older participants, and used the group as an "include" filter.

Set up an event, of the right type, so that it would get fired.

Added contacts to the event (and gave them the "Attended" status.

Created the webform and including (from the CiviCRM tab):

- existing contact
- firstname
- lastname
- contact ID
- checksum

then in the "Event Registration" section

- show past events: all
- Registration Options > Disable unregistering participants: yes
- Registration Options > Allow events populated from URL: yes
- under Contact1
- no of event sets for contact1: 1
- event(s): User Select
- & any needed participant custom fields

and build the checksummed url:

> [http://example.com/node/xxx?event1={event.event_id}&cid={contact.contact_id}&checksum={contact.checksum}](http://example.com/node/xxx?event1=%7Bevent.event_id%7D&cid=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D&checksum=%7Bcontact.checksum%7D)

think that's it.
let me know if I missed a bit (or did anything stupid!) and I'll correct it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tip. But what this "c1event1" referes to? it doesnt seems to render in my email.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- Find all your Event Participants in CiviCRM -> Email them a link to a
  Webform_CiviCRM that contains a checksum token to invite them to the Survey
- On that Webform_CiviCRM -> create your Questions - Consider not storing this data in CiviCRM -> with native Webform Elements you can do awesome surveys -> with Grid widgets (e.g.: indicate your excitement level about Webform_CiviCRM from: 'not at all excited' to 'moderately excited' to 'super exicited');
- Furthermore you can easily chart your Webform Surveys with other modules like - Google Charts - for example: here's a four point grid question where 1 was defined as 'does not meet expectations' to 4 was defined as 'exceeds expectations' [image]

Comment: Yes if you set up a Scheduled Reminder (or send out manually) if you include the custom fields on the webform and use the checksum link that includes the event id then the form will load with the existing contacts registration info and add the custom fields info to their registration eg node/xx?cid1={contact.contact_id}&event1={event.event_id}&{contact.checksum}

Comment: Thanks Pete, I have it all working (having to 'show past events' and hide the field got me for a while(!)), but the checksum doesn't seem to populate the fields.  read docs, everything should be fine, but no banana's (as yet)... still trying, but a bit stuck :!

Comment: But you'd be restricted to the widgets that CiviCRM can handle (text area, text, select) - To get real feedback/survey answers [as in 'on a scale of 1-5 how would you rate the venue' or what did you think of the quality of the presentations?] - feedback that you can easily chart into tables/pies - handle that part on the webform side - and webform_civicrm can link it to your CiviCRM Contact - but the data lives in Drupal.

Comment: Sorry KarinG, I want to keep the data in Civi and be able to clear it from drupal.

Comment: got it though... it needs "access published content", and just {contact.checksum}, I cleverly managed to put checksum={contact.checksum}... poor levels of patience and attention to detail, methinks!

Comment: Sorry - thought you were doing feedback/survey type of questions? If you just need textarea, text, simple select - those you can store in CiviCRM

Comment: Also, KarinG ... I have a scale of 1-5 (poor to Excellent) set up as an option group in Civi... just have to get a custom report to group if I need charts... ..nice plan though, cheers ;)

Comment: Right - that's a select? You can't do a grid though - for example: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/webform-grid-headings.png