# Changing CiviCRM events partcipant status

Tags: civievent

After all good things said about civicrm my question is: Is it any possibility to allow participant after an event registration to change status or other information related to that event?
I'm using drupal and civicrm.
Help will be appreciate.
Tanks

Comment: Hi 7480 (do you have a name?) - update your Q with your CMS, eg if using Drupal then a webform can do the above I expect, also in WP perhaps Caldera can

Comment: Hello thanks for repliying i've updated my question i'm using drupal. and civicrm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally it would be a civicrm user/ administrator that would update participant details after an event. (Rather than the participant themselves).

As Pete said you can configure a Drupal Webform to update participation details.

The answers to this question [How do I get Retrospective feedback for an event using a Webform (participant Custom Data)?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21394/how-do-i-get-retrospective-feedback-for-an-event-using-a-webform-participant-cu)

Shows how someone else has configured a webform, and the webform url (including event id and contact id) for use in a schedued reminder.

Comment: Hello Craig thanks for replying. Yor answer seams very usefull i was trying it but faced another weird thing: My webform is not showing civicrm tab. Do you have any idea what can cause this behaviour. Webform civicrm integration is well installed in my application. thanks

Comment: Can you check you have the drupal permission to create/ edit webform content?

Also in the webform permissions do you have the following permission:
Content authors: access and edit webform components and settings 

If the answer is yes, to all these- I'm stumped- perhaps try clearing drupal and civicrm caches?

Comment: Yes i have permission to create and edit webform content.I've cleaned all caches thanks.

Comment: finally have a solution with webform. thanks