# Webform CiviCRM 'Registration Status' for Event not Updating each subission

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

We're using the latest on D7 to have a nice RSVP form for an event. We made a custom status 'Not Attending' and of course have 'Registered' as the other status. The form has 4 contacts on it, cloned, all with the same stuff. No prices, just name/email/phone for 4 contacts with the RSVP field (civicrm_1_participant_1_participant_status_id)

When they first submit the form their choice is saved, works great.

But, when they return to the form, and submit again with a change in RSVP, the update is not reflected on their civicrm participant record.

Is this by design, or an error I have made? I assumed it would be cool to let people change their mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure from your description how exactly your form is configured. For the update participant status you may need a second form and specific url to reach it which includes the user's contact id and the event id.

See the responses to this question for more (and clearer) details:
[How do I get Retrospective feedback for an event using a Webform (participant Custom Data)?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21394/how-do-i-get-retrospective-feedback-for-an-event-using-a-webform-participant-cu)

Comment: Got it, that makes sense, I was hoping the form that created the Event Registration could be used additionally for RSVP changes - it seems kind of cludgy to have to maintain two. Anyhow, I appreciate your answer I'll accept it.